# Vudu and Spotify Download Location

Tags: windows-8.1, download, symbolic-link, spotify, junction

Vudu and Spotify both store the offline/downloaded files in 'AppData/Roaming' and I have maxed out my 'C' Drive. I want to move it to my larger 'D' Drive. I looked up what to do and all over the forums people said doing a symbolic link (Vudu) and junction (Spotify) worked for them. Created the symbolic link and junction in order to change the location, but:

1. It didn't solve my hard drive space issue because it just started downloading to both places.
2. Vudu movies didn't play and told me "if you have the movies downloaded on an SD card be sure it is plugged in". Then Spotify didn't even recognize they were downloaded when I went into offline mode.

---

**So this is what I did. Can you tell me if I did it wrong or if I need to do something else or more?**

For Vudu:

1. close Vudu to Go
2. rename Vudu to Go's `C:` drive's folder: `\com.vudu.air.Downloader`
   to something like: `\com.vudu.air.Downloader.disable`
3. run command prompt as admin
4. type `MKLINK /D C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader D:\Vudu\VUDUToGo\com.vudu.air.Downloader`            
   <sub>(That's all one line.)</sub>
5. open the `C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader.disabled` folder and you'll see two folders,
   named `airversion` and `Local Store`

   - select both folders and 'cut' them,
   - then go to your new drive/folder location where you want them moved to
6. load "Vudo to Go" and, in the app, under the "My Downloads" tab, you should now see all your movies you've downloaded (but now you're seeing them from your new drive storage location).

… except, when I opened the app, it asked for my login credentials again (when usually it just remembers) and my downloads weren't there. So I hit download and it was instantly there. But I don't think it was from my `D` drive because it was also back in my `C` Drive again.

---

For Spotify I did the same thing, I just used:

1. Exit Spotify
2. Go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Spotify` and delete the `Storage` folder
3. Open command prompt as admin
4. Enter: `mklink /J "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Spotify\Storage" "location you want to save it"`                
   <sub>(That's all one line.)</sub>
5. `MKLINK /J C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Spotify\Storage D:\Spotify\Storage`

… and it worked, but the storage folder came back, and when I downloaded the files, yes they went into the new folder, but they also went into the old file at the same time.

---

So if anything I added to my storage problem.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you create the target directories **before** creating the link?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that. I only did what's listed above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Replace **UserName** with logged in user's folder name throughout

1. Close Vudu To Go
2. To create a Junction link that re-directs VUDU to go to from C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader to D:\Vudu\VUDUToGo\com.vudu.air.Downloader

a. Start > Run > %AppData%

b. Add .old to the folder at the end of the path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader (com.vudu.air.Downloader.old)

c. Create D:\Vudu\VUDUToGo\com.vudu.air.Downloader

d. open Cmd prompt as admin

e. MKLINK /j C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader D:\Vudu\VUDUToGo\com.vudu.air.Downloader

To Delete the Junction link and revert back to default Vudu To Go folder

a. RD C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader

b. Start > Run > %AppData%

c. Create the rest of the folder path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader

d. Copy Data from D:\Vudu\VUDUToGo\com.vudu.air.Downloader to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.vudu.air.Downloader

Delete D:\Vudu\VUDUToGo\com.vudu.air.Downloader **OR** add .old to the end of the folder if you want to verify functionality before deleting it (com.vudu.air.Downloader.old)